# Add Ruby SDK from Docker container as a remote SDK on RubyMine

Tags: ssh, docker

Rubymine has options to add remote sdks using Vagrant and SSH, however I decided to go with Docker. I already created a Ruby container, but I don't know how to enable SSH access to it so Rubymine can set it as the remote SDK.

Is it possible?

Tried to follow this article, but the Ruby image doesn't have yum and this package epel-release is for Fedora/RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

Hey are you using this [official Ruby docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/)?

If so, it's based on Debian and you'll have to use apt-get to install packages.
Here's a handy script for installing openssh-server and configuring a user in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.1.9
#======================
# Install OpenSSH server (sshd)
#======================
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    openssh-server \
  && echo "PidFile ${RUN_DIR}/sshd.pid" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && sed -i 's|session    required     pam_loginuid.so|session    optional     pam_loginuid.so|g' /etc/pam.d/sshd \
  && mkdir -p /var/run/sshd \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user rubymine with password rubymine and give ownership of rubymine home dir
RUN adduser --quiet rubymine \
  && echo "rubymine:rubymine" | chpasswd \
  && chown -R rubymine:rubymine /home/rubymine \
EXPOSE 22
```

I'm not sure of what are the exact configurations you can perform with Rubymine. But it's possible to open a tty with the container without the need of ssh:

```
#run it as a daemon
docker run -d --name=myruby ruby:2.19 
#connect to it
docker -it exec myruby /bin/bash
```

**UPDATE**:

Try setting **DOCKER_HOST** environment variable to listen on a tcp port:

```
export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://localhost:2376'
```

Comment: I'm using the official image. Rubymine asks for the host and port to connect to via ssh. Tried creating a Dockerfile as you suggested and exposed port 22 as 2000 on host, however Rubymine says that the connection has been refused.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira What is your host OS? Are you using Docker toolbox? If so you need to set the ip to the boot2docker VirtualBox machine that Docker toolbox creates. You can discover that by using `docker-machine ls` and then `docker-machine ip <listed_vm>`

Comment: I'm using Docker for Windows beta and I'm using the IP that MobyLinuxVM is using. This VM if the equivalent of the default VM for Docker when using Virtual Box

Comment: Have you exposed the port 22 in the Dockerfile? I forgot to add it in the first answer then I edited that.

Comment: Yes, I exposed port 22 as port 2000 and it is listed as an open port.